# Merging two data frames on a common column in python

Tags: python

#Merging the individual datasets on a common field, the Loyalty Card Number (LYLTY_CARD_NBR)

```
Customer_Data = pd.merge(Transaction_data, Purchase_behaviour, on=Transaction_data['LYLTY_CARD_NBR'])
```

But I'm getting this error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-13c21c7d1662> in <module>
      1 #Merging the individual datasets on a common field, the Loyalty Card Number (LYLTY_CARD_NBR)
----> 2 Customer_Data = pd.merge(Transaction_data, Purchase_behaviour, on=Transaction_data['LYLTY_CARD_NBR'])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
     72     validate=None,
     73 ) -> "DataFrame":
---> 74     op = _MergeOperation(
     75         left,
     76         right,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in __init__(self, left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, axis, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
    650             self.right_join_keys,
    651             self.join_names,
--> 652         ) = self._get_merge_keys()
    653 
    654         # validate the merge keys dtypes. We may need to coerce

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in _get_merge_keys(self)
    994                     else:
    995                         if rk is not None:
--> 996                             right_keys.append(right._get_label_or_level_values(rk))
    997                             join_names.append(rk)
    998                         else:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_label_or_level_values(self, key, axis)
   1561             values = self.axes[axis].get_level_values(key)._values
   1562         else:
-> 1563             raise KeyError(key)
   1564 
   1565         # Check for duplicates

KeyError: 0          47142
1          55073
2          55073
3          58351
4          68193
           ...  
264831    242159
264832    244213
264833    256018
264834    257079
264835    265006
Name: LYLTY_CARD_NBR, Length: 264836, dtype: int64
```

Comment: What is the final error message at the bottom? Error messages have a summary statement at the bottom that explain the issue/and can be copy/pasted into Google for additional support.

Comment: I just added it to the initial comment.

Comment: Please don't post images of the error, rather copy and paste the full error traceback and format it with codeblocks (three backticks above and below the first and last lines of the error). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the column name 'LYLTY_CARD_NBR' is present in both Transaction_data and Purchase_behaviour dataframes, the value for option on= should be just the column name.

```
Customer_Data = pd.merge(Transaction_data, Purchase_behaviour, on='LYLTY_CARD_NBR')
```

I will recommend to pay attention to the type of merge to be performed:
how{‘left’, ‘right’, ‘outer’, ‘inner’, ‘cross’}, default is ‘inner’.

```
Customer_Data = pd.merge(Transaction_data, Purchase_behaviour, on='LYLTY_CARD_NBR', how='inner')
```

Please see the reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html